# building a dataframe from grouped data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
            x1     x2    .....      sig
 Index
   0        2      4     .....       B
   1        5      3     .....       A
   .        .      .                 .
   .        .      .     .....       .
```

`sig` gets only values A and B. the `x`'s can be as many as you like. then I `group` and `average` like this (also over all `x`'s):

```
v1 = df.groupby('sig')['x1'].mean()
v2 = df.groupby('Sig')['x2'].mean()
...
```

then I want to create a dataframe with the `means` in the `x`'s columns:

```
 d = {'x1': v1, 'x2': v2, ....}
 df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

that should look like this in the end:

```
     x1   x2 ........
sig
 A    3    2  ........
 B    5    3  ........
```

my question is: how can I create this dataframe in the end regarding the fact that the number of x's can get pretty large? so that means looping through the columns and extending the dictionary that is used for the dataframe (the dictionary solution is not necessary).

Comment: that should be `df.groupby('sig').mean()`

Comment: yes, that's right. that solves it. Thanks, @piRSquard. But in fact I would still be interested on how to construct the looping through and extending the dataframe/dictionary...

Comment: I'd `d = {c: df.groupby('sig')[c].mean() for c in df}`

Comment: tried to apply that to real data and resulted in DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Comment: oh yeah, I forgot about 'sig'. I'd `d = {c: df.groupby('sig')[c].mean() for c in df.drop('sig', 1)}`

Comment: perfect! many thanks